# How to deal with tight infinite streams?

Tags: dart, flutter, reactive-programming

I'm trying to write a fully reactive hello-world example in Flutter, specifically, a simple counter. Here, I have a null-stream from a "+1" button which gets triggered on button press:

```dart
class ReactiveButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = StreamController();
  Stream<void> pressedEvent;
  final text;

  ReactiveButton({this.text = ""}) {
    pressedEvent = _controller.stream;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => _controller.sink.add(null),
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to convert that stream into a sequence of natural numbers to feed into an `RxText`. So I use the `zipWith` method from rxdart with a tight stream of natural numbers, discarding the null value. Now the problem is that using the stream of natural numbers created by a tight `while (true)` loop results in an infinite cycle because (presumably) the stream never returns control between `yield`s:

```dart
Stream<int> naturals() async* {
  int count = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield count++;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I can use `Stream.periodic` constructor with a close to zero period. However, this results into my application gradually becoming sluggish (presumably, due to the streams indefinitely counting in vain).

So what I need is a lazy stream that only produces values when asked (immediately). That actually sounds like an `Iterable` but for `Iterable` I don't have a method to zip it with a stream. I thought about implementing a function which takes a list of streams/iterables and returns a stream of lists, working more or less like the regular zipper. It seems rather complicated though, and I'm not sure I can write a production-ready implementation.

The question is: what are my options? Is there a ready-to-go solution for this? Should I at all try to go full reactive with Flutter?

Comment: i dont get it: how fast do you want your counter to be incremented? and what is that `RaisedButton` used for?

Comment: @pskink Each time the button is pressed, of course.

Comment: so what do you want that `while (true) {` loop for? simply call `sink.add(cnt++)` inside `onPressed` callback

Comment: @pskink I want that loop to get the natural numbers sequence. I don't want to introduce any state in my widgets, that's the poing.

Comment: simply call `sink.add(cnt++)` inside `onPressed` callback

Comment: @pskink That would make my button emit numbers. What I need is a general-purpose reactive button. It should emit nulls or something like that.

Comment: so read [Asynchronous Programming: Streams](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams) on how to modify your stream - [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods) and [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams#transform-function) can be useful in particular

Comment: and of course you can use any other `StreamTransfomer` like those from [stream_transform](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/stream_transform) package

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I've already read all of this. I can transform streams imperatively. But I wanted to make a little library with primitives to work with streams declaratively, as in functional reactive programming.

Comment: and what stops you from creating that library?

Comment: @pskink The fact that the dart runtime doesn't have tight infinite streams in mind, and so I must resort to ad-hoc imperative stream transformers or to come up with a clever combinator like zipWith that works both with Streams and Iterables.

Comment: i have no idea what would be those "tight infinite streams"` useful for... - if you want to transform some stream write a `StreamTransformer`